# Find max subset of tree with max distance not greater than K

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I run into a dynamic programming problem on interviewstreet named "Far Vertices".

The problem is like:

> You are given a tree that has N vertices and N-1 edges. Your task is
>   to mark as small number of verices as possible so that the maximum
>   distance between two unmarked vertices be less than or equal to K. You
>   should write this value to the output. Distance between two vertices i
>   and j is defined as the minimum number of edges you have to pass in
>   order to reach vertex i from vertex j.

I was trying to do dfs from every node of the tree, in order to find the max connected subset of the nodes, so that every pair of subset did not have distance more than K.
But I could not define the state, and transitions between states.

Is there anybody that could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be able to get this down to O(N^2) by iteratively pruning the subtree with the minimum number of leaves that contribute to the longest path. I'll work out the details and post an answer in a bit.

Comment: Sorry, the greedy approach isn't working for me. You would have to find the optimal combination of the 0..k lowest levels of each subtree which would make the complexity greater than Techmonk's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few basic things I can notice (maybe very obvious to others):
1. There is only one route possible between two given vertices.
2. The farthest vertices would be the one with only one outgoing edge.

Now to solve the issue.

1. I would start with the set of Vertices that have only one edge and call them EDGE[] calculate the distances between the vertices in EDGE[]. This will give you (EDGE[i],EDGE[j],distance ) value pairs
2. For all the vertices pairs in EDGE that have a distance of > K, DO EDGE[i].occur++,EDGE[i].distance = MAX(EDGE[i].distance, distance)
   EDGE[j].occur++,EDGE[j].distance = MAX(EDGE[j].distance, distance)
3. Find the CANDIDATES in EDGE[] that have max(distance) from those Mark the with with max (occur)
4. Repeat till all edge vertices pair have distance less then or equal to K

Comment: I think your algorithm should be able to calculate the right result.
But the time complexity is exponential, and not acceptable. There should be some dynamic algorithm solving this problem.

Comment: This would be O(n^3). Not really exponential. And I think with a decent implementation of finding distance maybe even O(n^2*log(n))

Comment: Techmonk, sorry that I don't really understand your solution.
Per my current understanding, let's say we have a tree with 5 nodes, and the tree have edges like (1,2)/(2,3)/(3,4)/(4,5). K is 1.
Then the first thing is to find all the vertices pairs that have maximum distance, which is (1,5). Then we need to try deleting 1 or 5.
We have 2 options here, each one has a subtree with 4 nodes.
Then if we keep doing this in recursive way, this would be exponential. Am I understanding your solution wrong?

Comment: Maybe I should have elaborated the step 2 a bit more. You chose a node to remove based on the number of times it occurs in the maximum distance pair, since here both only occur once you can remove either one and the answer would not change. This is because these are the end nodes and are not influencing any other pair. E.G. if you had (1,2)/(2,3)/(3,4)/(4,5)/(4,6) Then the max would give you (1,5) and (1,6) and in this case you will remove 1 as it occurs most in the pairs that have Max distance. similarly in next step remove 2 then 3 and finally either of 5 or 6 to leave 4 and (5/6) unmarked

Comment: You can find the all pairs shortest paths (or rather, all pairs unique paths, as you observe) in O(N^2), if that helps your complexity any.

Comment: Sorry I tried the algorithm, and found a case that your algorithm did not work. The case is n=12,k=3,edges are (1 3)/(2 3)/(3 4)/(4 5)/(4 6)/(6 7)/(7 8)/(8 9)/(9 10)/(10 11)/(10 12). In this case, the algorithm returned 7, actually the result should be 6.

Comment: The first iteration would give you back (1,11) (1,12) (2,11) (2,12) (5,11) (5,12) and in this case since 11 and 12 occur the most time you have to remove one of them and eventually following the logic you will get 6 as the answer

Comment: Every time when trying to find a node to mark, a weight should be calculated for every unmarked node. The weight of node x should be number of vertices that has distance larger than K from x. This is proved correct.

Answer (score 3):

The problem consists essentially of finding the largest subtree of diameter <= k, and subtracting its size from n. You can solve it using DP.

Some useful observations:

The diameter of a tree rooted at node v (T(v)) is:

- 1 if n has no children,
- max(diameter T(c), height T(c) + 1) if there is one child c,
- max(max(diameter T(c)) for all children c of v, max(height T(c1) + height T(c2) + 2) for all children c1, c2 of v, c1 != c2)

Since we care about maximizing tree size and bounding tree diameter, we can flip the above around to suggest limits on each subtree:

- For any tree rooted at v, the subtree of interest is at most k deep.
- If n is a node in T(v) and has no children <= k away from v, its maximum size is 1.
- If n has one child c, the maximum size of T(n) of diameter <= k is max size T(c) + 1.

Now for the tricky bit. If n has more than one child, we have to find all the possible tree sizes resulting from allocating the available depth to each child. So say we are at depth 3, k = 7, we have 4 depth left to play with. If we have three children, we could allocate all 4 to child 1, 3 to child 1 and 1 to child 2, 2 to child 1 and 1 to children 2 and 3, etc. We have to do this carefully, making sure we don't exceed diameter k. You can do this with a local DP.

What we want for each node is to calculate maxSize(d), which gives the max size of the tree rooted at that node that is up to d deep that has diameter <= k. Nodes with 0 and 1 children are easy to figure this for, as above (for example, for one child, v.maxSize(i) = c.maxSize(i - 1) + 1, v.maxSize(0) = 1). Nodes with 2 or more children, you compute dp[i][j], which gives the max size of a k-diameter-bound tree using up to the ith child taking up to j depth. The recursion is dp[i][j] = max(child(i).maxSize(m - 1) + dp[i - 1][min(j, k - m)] for m from 1 to j. d[i][0] = 1. This says, try giving the ith child 1 to j depth, and give the rest of the available depth to the previous nodes. The "rest of the available depth" is the minimum of j, the depth we are working with, or k - m, because depth given to child i + depth given to the rest cannot exceed k. Transfer the values of the last row of dp to the maxSize table for this node. If you run the above using a depth-limited DFS, it will compute all the necessary maxSize entries in the correct order, and the answer for node v is v.maxSize(k). Then you do this once for every node in the tree, and the answer is the maximum value found.

Sorry for the muddled nature of the explanation. It was hard for me to think through, and difficult to describe. Working through a few simple examples should make it clearer. I haven't calculated the complexity, but n is small, and it went through all the test cases in .5 to 1s in Scala.

Comment: when you say dp[i][0] = 1, this is for current root node, right?